# Can I upload a new binary but with the same version number to the Apple iTunes Connect for an app with Ready for Sale status?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I submitted an app on Apple's iTunes Connect portal with version number 2.2 almost 3 months ago and it is in the Ready for Sale status as of now.

Now, I have a requirement to submit a new binary of the app with the same version record (2.2) on iTunes Connect (without creating a new record). I see that I cannot edit my version record on iTunes Connect.

But is it possible that if I increase the Build number in my Info.plist file and keep the Version number as 2.2 itself, will I be able to upload a new binary on the same iTunes Connect record via Xcode?

Also, if the above is possible, will the users who have already installed the app on their device receive an app update notification for this binary?

Comment: No, you need to increase the version number..

Comment: @SidShah - Thanks for the information. So, can I create a new iTunes record with version number as 2.2.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now, I have a requirement to submit a new binary of the app with the same version record (2.2)

You can't. Once an app has gone on sale, iTunes connect will not accept a new binary unless you up the version number.

Comment: Thanks for the information. So, can I create a new iTunes record with version number as 2.2.1?

Comment: Absolutely. iTunes Connect doesn't care what your system for incrementing is: 2.2.1 will do, 2.3 will do, 3.0 will do, and so forth. You simply have to increment _somehow_. And once you do that, all will be well and the notification to users will work normally.